# Help regarding Meteor Pub/Sub

Tags: meteor, mongodb-query, meteor-helper

I have more than one million records in mongo collection.
It is obviously is bad strategy to send all these record to client browser.

So, I created a publish function which just return count for "Searched" parameter only amongst those million records.

`Meteor.publish('count', function(query) {
  return Collection.find({ fieldName : "query" }).count();
});`

So, I got response from above query in following format.

`We are counting for pain and count is [object Object]`

I want to show the count from above publication,But I receive objects only in response not number. Though When I executed this same query in dev console then , it did showed "Number" as output.

Where am I going wrong?
Can anyone show me a simple example that helps this to resolve?

Comment: Have a look in the Meteor docs at the counts-by-room example: http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_publish (search for `Meteor.publish("counts-by-room"`)

Answer (score 0):

There is a package for it: https://atmospherejs.com/tmeasday/publish-counts

Simply call Counts.publish within a publication, passing in a name and a cursor:

```
//server code
Meteor.publish('posts', function() {
  Counts.publish(this, 'postsCount', Posts.find());
  return Posts.find({}, { limit: 10 });
});
```

Subscribe on the client:

```
Meteor.subscribe('posts');
```

Then just call `Counts.get('postsCount');` to get counter number. For example in your helper:

```
Template.posts.helpers({
  postsCount: function() {
    return Counts.get('postsCount');
  }
});
```